# Any alternatives to the JAXB XJC-compiler reference implementation from glassfish?

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc

I am wondering if there are any alternatives to the reference implementation of the JAXB XJC-compiler from Glassfish!? Don't understand me wrong, the XJC is working fine. But if this is the "reference implementation", there muste be other implementations. is there any from IBM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not had experience with either of these, but there is [Apache JaxMe](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/webservices/archive/jaxme/site/index.html) and <del>[EclipseLink MOXy](http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php)</del>.

**Update:**

According to Blaise Doughan below, MOXy uses the reference implementation.

Comment: MOXy leverages the XJC tool from the JAXB RI.

Comment: NOTE: Apache JaxMe is retired